# Using multi-line PowerShell commands from cmd.exe

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to specify a multi-line PowerShell command in a cmd.exe .bat script. I clearly do not yet have the right line continuation and/or quoting. I also tried using a backtick as the line continuation character with similar failure. How can I enter this correctly?

```
PS C:\src\t> cat .\pd.bat
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path '../' -Filter '*.doc' | ^
    Select-Object -First 1 | ^
    ForEach-Object { notepad `"$_.FullName`" }"
PS C:\src\t> .\pd.bat

C:\src\t>powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path '../' -Filter '*.doc' | ^
^ : The term '^' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:45
+ Get-ChildItem -Path '../' -Filter '*.doc' | ^
+                                             ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (^:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Why use cmd.exe in the first place? Just type the command you want directly from the PowerShell prompt.

Comment: Especially where the only advantage `cmd.exe` has over PowerShell is memory footprint (several orders of magnitude smaller). If you are going to launch powershell, just use powershell.

Comment: I want to learn what mechanisms are required to put PowerShell into .bat scripts because some people will never let go of the cmd shell. This also goes toward letting people use whatever they are comfortable with. If they see that PowerShell is more powerful and readable, perhaps they will start using more PowerShell commands. This is a long process, not an overnight change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short of using an intermediate temporary file you can use **selective `^`-escaping**:

```bash
powershell -NoProfile -Command Get-ChildItem -Path '../' -Filter '*.doc' ^| ^
  Select-Object -First 1 ^| ^
  ForEach-Object { notepad "\"$($_.FullName)\"" }
```

<sup>Note that `notepad "$_.FullName"` wouldn't work in PowerShell, because you need an enclosing `$(...)` to reference *properties* inside `"..."`. I've corrected the issue above, but note that you don't need the double quotes at all in this case.</sup>

`^` must be used:

- to escape `|` to prevent `cmd.exe` from interpreting it up front.

  - Generally, you have to `^`-escape *all* of `cmd.exe`'s metacharacters if you want to pass them through to PowerShell: `& | < > %`
  - `"` instances that you want PowerShell to see *literally* (for them to then have *syntactic* meaning when interpreted as PowerShell source code) are a special case: you must `\`-escape them (!) *and* `"..."`-enclose the string you want to be recognized as a *single* argument by PowerShell, so as to preserve *embedded whitespace* accurately.
  - **Note**: You **can *not* use `"..."` quoting around the *entire* `-Command`** argument, because `cmd.exe` doesn't support multi-line string literals (`^` inside `"..."` is interpreted *literally*), and *per-line* `"..."` quoting works *only* if each such line *starts with whitespace*.
- to escape *line endings* to tell `cmd.exe` that the command continues on the next line.

  - Note that the `^` must be the very last character on the line.
  - Also note that a line-ending `^` *removes* the line break, so the resulting command is a *single*-line command.

To **include actual line breaks** in your command - which are *required* for passing commands to a language such as Python with `python -c`, as [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)  points out - use `^<newline><newline>`, as [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) recommends:

```bash
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "\"line 1^

line 2\""
```

The above yields (based on PowerShell simply *echoing* (outputting) a quoted string literal submitted as a command):

```bash
line 1
line 2
```

<sup>Note: The `"\"` (and matching `\""`) is not only required to ultimately pass the string with embedded whitespace preserved correctly here, but also to present a *balanced* set of `"` on that line to `cmd.exe` (irrespective of `\`-escaping, which `cmd.exe` doesn't recognize) - without it, the newline-escaping `^` at the end of that line wouldn't be recognized.</sup>

PetSerAl also points out that if you're passing what PowerShell should regard a string *literal*, you can also pass what PowerShell ends up seeing as a *single-quoted* string (`'...'`):

```bash
powershell.exe -noprofile -command ^"'line 1^

line 2'^"
```

Here, the `^`-escaping of the `"` instances are for the benefit of `cmd.exe` so it doesn't mistake the newline-escaping `^` as being inside a double-quoted string.

Comment: I found that it was working without the subexpression in PowerShell because I was not quoting it. `{ notepad $_.FullName }` works, while `{ notepad "$_.FullName" }` fails. Using the subexpression inside the quotes produces the desired result. This seems odd.

Comment: @lit: It may be surprising, but that's how it works in PowerShell - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) of mine.

Comment: I will bookmark this post to use it as duplicate closures.

Answer (score 2):

I second Bill_Stewart's comment to just do it in the native PowerShell console; no need for cmd.

Should you *need* to do it in cmd, use quote marks for each line before using `^`. And remove the backtick from within the `ForEach-Object` block.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path '../' -Filter '*.doc' |" ^
"Select-Object -First 1 ^| ^
"ForEach-Object { notepad "$_.FullName" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the opposite and collapse my command down to 1 line when possible. You can do this by terminating commands with ; just like javascript or c#. In your case, I don't even see a need to use a terminator. You can just roll this into one line:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path '../' -Filter '*.doc' |     Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object { notepad `"$_.FullName`" }"
```

another option would be to save your PowerShell to an external file and call it:

`powershell.exe -File MyPSScript.ps1`

Answer (score 1):

The pd.bat content must be the following:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command Get-ChildItem -Path '../' -Filter '*.doc' ^| ^
    Select-Object -First 1 ^| ^
    ForEach-Object { notepad $_.FullName }
```