# how to run multiple powershell command inside .bat

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, active-directory, command-prompt

I made a batch file for joining computers to domain.

```
Powershell -command " Add-Computer -DomainName blabla.com -Credential blabla\bla "
```

works but I also want to add -Description with input.

```
Powershell -command "
$date = Get-Date
$cred= read-host -prompt 'IT username' 
Add-Computer -DomainName blabla.com  -Description "joined domain by $cred date $date" -Credential blabla\$cred "
```

did not work.

```
Powershell -command " $date = Get-Date "
Powershell -command " $cred= read-host -prompt 'IT username' "
Powershell -command " Add-Computer -DomainName blabla.com  -Description "joined domain by $cred date $date" -Credential blabla\$cred "
```

didnt work either.

Please I need help

Comment: Welcome to SO, Berke the Vulpes. Each individual invocation of `powershell.exe` does not know what the other did. The commands can be in one PowerShell invocation by using a SEMICOLON at the end of each line.

Comment: You need just one execution of PowerShell, and multiple commands passed to it. Each of those commands should be separated with semicolons, `;`, and should all be enclosed within one doublequoted `-Command` argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using multi-line PowerShell commands from cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224759/using-multi-line-powershell-commands-from-cmd-exe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs to be done in a single invocation of `powershell.exe`. Terminate each PowerShell statement with a SEMICOLON and use the `cmd` line continuation character, CARET `^`.

```
powershell -command ^
$date = Get-Date; ^
$cred= read-host -prompt 'IT username'; ^
Add-Computer -DomainName blabla.com  -Description "joined domain by $cred date $date" -Credential blabla\$cred;
```

The reason this needs to be one invocation is that separate invocations of PowerShell do not know what each other has done.

This is not tested. There may be some `cmd` syntax issues, typically about quoting. It would be easier to have the .bat file script call a PowerShell script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dpDo-JoinDomain.ps1"
```

Note that `Do` is not an approved PowerShell verb. Use the command `Get-Verb` to find one you think is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
Powershell -command " $date = Get-Date; $cred= read-host -prompt 'IT username'; add-Computer -DomainName tpicomp.com -Description "joined domain by $cred date $date" -Credential tpicomp\$cred "
```

thanks for  @lit and @Compo     here is the final result.