# Split .bat command into multiple lines

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I prepared a command that works and does its job correctly

`powershell -Command "(gc copy.json) -replace 'field_type','field_name' -replace 'aaa','AAA' -replace 'Bbb','BBB' | Out-File copy12345.json"`

But I would like each '-replace ...' to be on a new line for better readability.
I tried the following solution and also brackets for the whole command, but it didn't help.

```
powershell -Command "(gc copy.json) ^
-replace 'field_type', 'field_name' ^
-replace 'aaa','AAA' ^
-replace 'Bbb','BBB' ^
| Out-File kopia12345.json"
```

Comment: it is inside double quotes, meaning the line is passed to `powershell` which uses backticks. but now you're sitting with a problem where cmd does not understand what you want. Why not run this directly from `powershell` instead? Anyway, leave the carets as is and remove the outer double quotes and it should work.

Comment: Gerhard is correct. The linked duplicate discusses all requirements in detail, notably not being able to use `"..."` for overall quoting (as noted) and needing to `^`-escape `|` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell -Command "(gc copy.json) `
-replace 'field_type','field_name' `
-replace 'aaa','AAA' `
-replace 'Bbb','BBB' `
| Out-File copy12345.json"
```

reference: [https://shellgeek.com/powershell-multiline-command/#:~:text=To%20split%20long%20command%20into,split%20it%20into%20multiple%20lines](https://shellgeek.com/powershell-multiline-command/#:%7E:text=To%20split%20long%20command%20into,split%20it%20into%20multiple%20lines).

Comment: This will not work. sorry, it is being launched from `cmd` and `cmd` does not know what ` is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks   may be this can help you

Comment: Sorry, Addy, but still not relevant. See my comment to the answer and also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224759/using-multi-line-powershell-commands-from-cmd-exe)