# Trouble starting PowerShell script from .bat file with multi-line parameters

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line-interface

I need to start a Powershell script from a .bat file and the Powershell script accepts parameters. Today, I run the script from a single line, like this:

```
cmd.exe /C pwsh.exe -Command "& {C:\temp\test.ps1 -ForceFullSync -AzureUserFilterOverride { $users | Where-Object { ($_.assignedLicenses.Count -ge 1) -and ($_.userPrincipalName -match 'domain\.com') } } -CompanyId bb8083d14755f910291fe0e8036d43ea -ManageObjects Contact -AzureUserPropertyList @(@{ msProp = 'accountEnabled'; mappedProp = 'active' }, @{ msProp = 'businessPhones'; mappedProp = 'phone' }, @{ msProp = 'givenName'; mappedProp = 'first_name' }, @{ msProp = 'mail'; mappedProp = 'email' }, @{ msProp = 'mobilePhone'; mappedProp = 'mobile_phone' }, @{ msProp = 'onPremisesImmutableId'; mappedProp = 'u_correlation_id' }, @{ msProp = 'surname'; mappedProp = 'last_name' }, @{ msProp = 'userPrincipalName'; mappedProp = 'user_name' }, @{ msProp = 'assignedLicenses'; mappedProp = '' }) -SecretId 120953 -AzureAdTenantDomain domain.onmicrosoft.com -ServiceNowBaseUri 'https://testinstance.service-now.com' -IdentityProviderSysId '5ffa40e4975a391077dd7a76f053afbf' -LogPath C:\temp\domain\log.txt -Verbose; Exit $LASTEXITCODE }"
```

That works *fine*, but is difficult to read (and will be getting longer with additional parameters), so I would like to break it by line. I tried the following:

```
cmd.exe /C pwsh.exe -Command "& {
    C:\temp\test.ps1 `
    -ForceFullSync `
    -AzureUserFilterOverride { `$users | Where-Object { ($_.assignedLicenses.Count -ge 1) -and ($_.userPrincipalName -match 'domain\.com') } } `
    -CompanyId bb8083d14755f910291fe0e8036d43ea `
    -ManageObjects Contact `
    -AzureUserPropertyList @(
        @{ msProp = 'accountEnabled'; mappedProp = 'active' },
        @{ msProp = 'businessPhones'; mappedProp = 'phone' },
        @{ msProp = 'givenName'; mappedProp = 'first_name' },
        @{ msProp = 'mail'; mappedProp = 'email' },
        @{ msProp = 'mobilePhone'; mappedProp = 'mobile_phone' },
        @{ msProp = 'onPremisesImmutableId'; mappedProp = 'u_correlation_id' },
        @{ msProp = 'surname'; mappedProp = 'last_name' },
        @{ msProp = 'userPrincipalName'; mappedProp = 'user_name' },
        @{ msProp = 'assignedLicenses'; mappedProp = '' }
    ) `
    -SecretId 120953 `
    -AzureAdTenantDomain domain.onmicrosoft.com `
    -ServiceNowBaseUri 'https://testinstance.service-now.com' `
    -IdentityProviderSysId '5ffa40e4975a391077dd7a76f053afbf' `
    -LogPath C:\temp\domain\log.txt `
    -Verbose; `
    Exit `$LASTEXITCODE
}"
```

But when I run the .bat file, all I get is Notepad opening c:\temp\test.ps1. When I close it, the command shell shows me:

> c:\temp>test.bat
>
> c:\temp>cmd.exe /C pwsh.exe -Command "& {C:\temp\test.ps1 `
>
> c:\temp>-ForceFullSync ` '-ForceFullSync' is not recognized as an
> internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> c:\temp>-AzureUserFilterOverride { `$users   | Where-Object { ($_.assignedLicenses.Count -ge 1) -and ($_.userPrincipalName -match 'domain\.com') } }`  '-AzureUserFilterOverride' is not recognized as
> an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> c:\temp>

Based on [Using multi-line PowerShell commands from cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224759/using-multi-line-powershell-commands-from-cmd-exe) I tried replacing the line-ending backticks with the caret character like this:

```
cmd.exe /C pwsh.exe -Command "& {
    C:\temp\test.ps1 ^
    -ForceFullSync ^
    -AzureUserFilterOverride { `$users | Where-Object { ($_.assignedLicenses.Count -ge 1) -and ($_.userPrincipalName -match 'domain\.com') } } ^
    -CompanyId bb8083d14755f910291fe0e8036d43ea ^
    -ManageObjects Contact ^
    -AzureUserPropertyList @(
        @{ msProp = 'accountEnabled'; mappedProp = 'active' },
        @{ msProp = 'businessPhones'; mappedProp = 'phone' },
        @{ msProp = 'givenName'; mappedProp = 'first_name' },
        @{ msProp = 'mail'; mappedProp = 'email' },
        @{ msProp = 'mobilePhone'; mappedProp = 'mobile_phone' },
        @{ msProp = 'onPremisesImmutableId'; mappedProp = 'u_correlation_id' },
        @{ msProp = 'surname'; mappedProp = 'last_name' },
        @{ msProp = 'userPrincipalName'; mappedProp = 'user_name' },
        @{ msProp = 'assignedLicenses'; mappedProp = '' }
    ) ^
    -SecretId 120953 ^
    -AzureAdTenantDomain domain.onmicrosoft.com ^
    -ServiceNowBaseUri 'https://testinstance.service-now.com' ^
    -IdentityProviderSysId '5ffa40e4975a391077dd7a76f053afbf' ^
    -LogPath C:\temp\domain\log.txt ^
    -Verbose; ^
    Exit `$LASTEXITCODE
}"
```

But then the shell said,

> c:\temp>test.bat
>
> c:\temp>cmd.exe /C pwsh.exe -Command "& {
>
> c:\temp>C:\temp\test.ps1     -ForceFullSync
> -AzureUserFilterOverride { `$users   | Where-Object { ($*.assignedLicenses.Count -ge 1) -and ($*.userPrincipalName -match
> 'domain.com') } }     -CompanyId bb8083d14755f910291fe0e8036d43ea
> -ManageObjects Contact     -AzureUserPropertyList @( 'Where-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> batch file.
>
> c:\temp>

I feel like I must be close, but am missing something small.

Comment: If you are running the command from within a batch file, that is already being executed by `cmd.exe`, so preceding your `pwsh.exe` command with `cmd.exe /C` seems completely redundant, and potentially problematic. Effectively sending everything as arguments, (to be first passed to another instance of cmd.exe), means that a round of parsing by that interpreter takes place before its resulting strings are then passed to `pwsh.exe`. I would strongly therefore advise that you begin by removing the first eleven characters from your command. You should also be using `-File` instead of `-Command`.

Comment: You need to use the full path of the pwsh.exe which is in the folder C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0.  Since all the cmd.exe commands are in powershell I would use an extension PS1 and run the bat as a powershell script.

Comment: The line continuation character in cmd.exe is a CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT `^` and not a GRAVE ACCENT `\`` as it is in pwsh.exe. How about putting the PowerShell code into an `Invoke-test.ps1` script as @Compo has suggested?

Comment: What problem are you solving by trying to do this using cmd.exe?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, In the batch file, I will concede that cmd.exe is likely redundant. I should be fine to drop it, but I still need to launch the Powershell script from a .bat file because of the method by which we monitor scheduled tasks. I tried using the answer Compo suggested, but the multi-line parameters are still causing problems without `cmd.exe /c`.

Comment: What does "because of the method by which we monitor scheduled tasks" mean?

Comment: The philosophical debate notwithstanding, only a few tweaks are needed to make Compo's answer work (I've left a comment). My answer explains the problems with your attempt and how to avoid them _in general_, which I think will benefit future readers more than spelling out a very specific solution (at least not without an explanation). Either way, I think the combination of the two answers should solve your problem.

Comment: Based on my experience, this may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). (I could be wrong, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct would be to try something like this:

```bash
@pwsh.exe -File "C:\temp\test.ps1"^
 -ForceFullSync^
 -AzureUserFilterOverride {^
   $users ^| Where-Object {^
    ($_.assignedLicenses.Count -ge 1) -and ($_.userPrincipalName -match 'domain\.com')^
   }^
  }^
 -CompanyId bb8083d14755f910291fe0e8036d43ea^
 -ManageObjects Contact^
 -AzureUserPropertyList @(^
   @{ msProp = 'accountEnabled'; mappedProp = 'active' },^
   @{ msProp = 'businessPhones'; mappedProp = 'phone' },^
   @{ msProp = 'givenName'; mappedProp = 'first_name' },^
   @{ msProp = 'mail'; mappedProp = 'email' },^
   @{ msProp = 'mobilePhone'; mappedProp = 'mobile_phone' },^
   @{ msProp = 'onPremisesImmutableId'; mappedProp = 'u_correlation_id' },^
   @{ msProp = 'surname'; mappedProp = 'last_name' },^
   @{ msProp = 'userPrincipalName'; mappedProp = 'user_name' },^
   @{ msProp = 'assignedLicenses'; mappedProp = '' }^
  )^
 -SecretId 120953^
 -AzureAdTenantDomain domain.onmicrosoft.com^
 -ServiceNowBaseUri 'https://testinstance.service-now.com'^
 -IdentityProviderSysId '5ffa40e4975a391077dd7a76f053afbf'^
 -LogPath 'C:\temp\domain\log.txt'^
 -Verbose
```

I removed the `Exit` with `$LASTEXITCODE` command, because that should already exist within the `test.ps`1 script.

---

**[Edit /]**

If `-File` does not work for you, you could try it like this using `-Command`, as per your original submission, instead:

```bash
@pwsh.exe -Command "C:\temp\test.ps1"^
 " -ForceFullSync"^
 " -AzureUserFilterOverride {"^
 "   $users | Where-Object {"^
 "    ($_.assignedLicenses.Count -ge 1) -and ($_.userPrincipalName -match 'domain\.com')"^
 "   }"^
 "  }"^
 " -CompanyId bb8083d14755f910291fe0e8036d43ea"^
 " -ManageObjects Contact"^
 " -AzureUserPropertyList @("^
 "   @{ msProp = 'accountEnabled'; mappedProp = 'active' },"^
 "   @{ msProp = 'businessPhones'; mappedProp = 'phone' },"^
 "   @{ msProp = 'givenName'; mappedProp = 'first_name' },"^
 "   @{ msProp = 'mail'; mappedProp = 'email' },"^
 "   @{ msProp = 'mobilePhone'; mappedProp = 'mobile_phone' },"^
 "   @{ msProp = 'onPremisesImmutableId'; mappedProp = 'u_correlation_id' },"^
 "   @{ msProp = 'surname'; mappedProp = 'last_name' },"^
 "   @{ msProp = 'userPrincipalName'; mappedProp = 'user_name' },"^
 "   @{ msProp = 'assignedLicenses'; mappedProp = '' }"^
 "  )"^
 " -SecretId 120953"^
 " -AzureAdTenantDomain domain.onmicrosoft.com"^
 " -ServiceNowBaseUri 'https://testinstance.service-now.com'"^
 " -IdentityProviderSysId '5ffa40e4975a391077dd7a76f053afbf'"^
 " -LogPath C:\temp\domain\log.txt"^
 " -Verbose;"^
 " Exit $LASTEXITCODE"
```

Comment: Tried this in my .bat file, but it says, "'Where-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Apologies, forgot to escape the pipe character. Updated code, please try again.

Comment: This probably works to prevent `cmd.exe`'s parsing errors, but the nature of the arguments being passed (arrays, hashtables) prevents use of `-File` and requires `-Command`. With the latter `; exit $LASTEXITCODE` _is_ necessary to pass the script's _specific_ exit code though (otherwise any nonzero one would be reported as `1`).

Comment: I have made an edit to include an untested `-Command` version too, @mklement0.

Answer (score 0):

- In a batch file, there's *no* reason to call an external program such as `powershell.exe` via `cmd.exe /C` - just call that program *directly*.
- There's *no* reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter<sup>[1]</sup> - just use `"..."` directly - but see below re *multiline* string use from `cmd.exe`
- The [answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45226027/45375) in your question spells out the relevant rules re *multiline* PowerShell CLI calls from `cmd.exe`, and these are the ones you *didn't* follow:

  - `cmd.exe` has *no* concept of *multiline* `"..."` strings, so your code cannot work.

    - You may use *per-line* `"..."` enclosure - inside of which you needn't worry about escaping `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&` and `|` - as long as each such line *starts with whitespace* and is terminated by an *unquoted* `^` for line continuation (for `cmd.exe`'s benefit).
  - *Every line* in a multiline statement must be terminated with `^` - irrespective of whether a given  block of lines happens to form a single *PowerShell* construct that *in PowerShell* doesn't need line continuations.
  - Additionally (these are things that your attempt *does* observe):

    - Only the `-Command` CLI parameter (which is the default in [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI) - not the `-File` parameter (which is the default in [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI) - accepts *arbitrary PowerShell code* to execute, which is needed in your case.
    - The end of each PowerShell statement *must explicitly signaled via `;`*, given that `cmd.exe`'s line continuations (`^`) do *not* introduce *newlines*.

For a complete overview of the rules for multiline PowerShell CLI calls from `cmd.exe` - including additional rules that must be observed in the context of `for /f` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66085286/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected. Unfortunately, this anti-pattern is still quite prevalent.</sup>